# how do I push successfully to git without getting error

Tags: git, github

getting an error while trying to push my code to github after adding a token on github

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/username/student-API.git/'
```

used git push, then got the error

Comment: Did something at the documentation link provided in the error message confuse you? Or do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Just getting this weird error, not sure what it is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remote%3A+Support+for+password+authentication+was+removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated on page linked directly in the error message you need to use [Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) instead of your Github password (that you normally use to login to Github) when `git` asks for password (or when you cache password using credential manager).

So, to make this work you need to go to **Settings** > **Developer Settings** > **Personal Access Tokens** and create either fine grained or classic token and then use that instead of password.